# Right-click on a table to to add to new Design Query in Access 2003 to 2007, 2010, 2013?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, keyboard-shortcuts, ms-access-2010

In Access 2003, I used to be able to right-click on a table and create a new query in Design View with that table already added. It always saved me some clicking. In the newer versions of Access I have to use the Create tab on the ribbon and click the Query Design icon. Are there any other shortcuts to quickly creating a query that I am missing? Maybe a keyboard shortcut?
The Quick-access toolbar is handy but I have hundreds of databases, and setting that up for each one is mind-numbing. Thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no known keyboard shortcut in newer versions of Access, nor is there a right-click shortcut.  For inexplicable reasons, Microsoft seems to have removed them.  You will have to use the ribbon, or you can add the Query Design function to the Quick Access Toolbar (the bar at the very top of Access which, by default, has the Save, Undo and Redo icons).

I did, however, discover that CTRL + G brings up the VBA screen, which I wasn't previously aware of.  :o)